# How can I ensure my Gradle xjc generation always happens for integrationTest targets?

Tags: gradle

Context:

Gradle multi-project build. Certain sub-projects generate and compile XSD -> Java -> *.class files. Naturally there are no integration tests present and there are also none in the projects that depends on maybe 3-4 of these. What this means is that if you run:

```
gradle clean cITJ
```

...no `build/generated-src/java` is created, however the build constructs the `*.war` files correctly. Not sure if I understand why. I'm assuming it has to do with the daemon or caching. The problem is with the IDE's (Half of us use IntelliJ and the other half, Eclipse). They expect those files to be present, so we would prefer that they regenerate for all 3 targets, cJ, cIJ and cITJ.

For the record, this also does not help the situation:

```
outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
```

What's the most efficient way to make cITJ trigger cJ in my XSD schema sub-projects to support our IDE's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after `cITJ.dependsOn cJ`

Comment: 1. I obey with exception. IMHO, some of the rules hereon show a certain social ignorance that is common in our field of work. Regardless of Stack's policies, social skills have value. Wars have been fought for the simple lack of "Please?" and "Thank you."
2. Because it works. ;-) 
3. I think it's because integrationTest is a contrived task that would not normally be present in these projects.  AFIK, integrationTest is not a built-in.

Comment: You can modify any task, whether it is "built-in" or not. Actually no task is built-in, but all are added either by you or by plugins that you apply.